# Cause of actor termination or how to handle error

Tags: akka

When actor fails, i need to send cause of failure to another actor.

I know there are supervision strategies and i use them. The problem is - i cannot find correct place for such error reporting. 
I tried watching actor, but Terminated message does not provide cause of termination.
Currently, i added error handling in Decider:

```
  override def supervisorStrategy: SupervisorStrategy =
    OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10, withinTimeRange = Duration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), loggingEnabled = true) {
      case e: Exception =>
        onActorError(sender(), e)
        Stop
    }
```

But I think that it is not a good time and place to do so, "decider" should return strategy, and not implicitly do something else.

So the question is: is there a proper place to catch actor exceptions and do something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postRestart` method of the supervised actor seems like a good place to do the postmortem logging.
From [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Restart_Hooks):

> The new actor’s postRestart method is invoked with the exception which
>   caused the restart. By default the preStart is called, just as in the
>   normal start-up case.

Comment: Actor is stopped, not restarted. So postRestart will probably never be called

Comment: yes, but postStop has no arguments... So there is no way to determine cause of stop at that point

Comment: instead of returning Stop in the Strategy on the first exception, which makes the whole supervision point moot, you could let it with the default strategy which returns Restart by default on any Exception and do the logging bit and stopping in the post restart...

Comment: It has the same unobvious flow, as logging in decider: you set supervision strategy as Restart but in reality you stop actor right after expected restart. That is not clear strategy either :)

Comment: I guess, there is no vanilla way to do it, afterall. Thanks